# TinyMCE Paste from word not working properly

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-3

I have a problem with Paste From Word functionality. I have an editor and when I click the paste from word button it opens a popup with a textarea . I want to paste my text which contains simple text, an image () and a hyperlink. When I'm pasting the text everything seems to be fine but when I click the submit button in order for the editor to get the content it loses the images.

From popup I do a

`tinymcepopup.editor.execcommand('mceinsertclipboardcontent', false, {content : h, wordcontent : true});`

I've tried the `paste_data_images: true` and put the img to `extended_valid_elements` but nothing worked.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I manage to get it to work. Setting the `paste_data_images: true` did the trick. My problem in the first place was that the application that I was using had an extra file which was overriding my settings, so I changed there and everything works as expected.